# Angular and Server Sent Events: close method call does not close the data stream

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

Tech stack: Angular 7, Spring webflux (with spring boot), Chrome browser

I cannot share the actual code due to policy restrictions. Appreciate your understanding.

I have followed this example: https://medium.com/@chrisbautistaaa/server-sent-events-in-angular-node-908830cc29aa

I have a boolean variable makeCall acting as a condition switch for my if else
When user clicks a button on screen *toggleSseCall* method containing the below logic is called in Angular component

**Body of toggleSseCall method:**

```
makeCall: boolean = true;

toggleSseCall() {
   let eventSource = new EventSource(url);
    if(makeCall) {
        Call service method: getServerSentEvents(eventSource) //similar to the example in link one difference being i'm passing the Instantiated eventSource reference
        Subscribe to the observable returned by the above call like in the example and console log the data 
    } else {  //When user clicks the button again, call goes here as makeCall is false
        //Call flow comes here as expected, I verified that with console logging
        eventSource.close(); //I verified to make sure the close method is not uppercase or anything like that
    }
    makeCall = !makeCall //toggle boolean flag
}
```

**Server side:**
Just RESTFul Get Api call that returns Flux and the Flux just returns hello string every x seconds

The call is happening and the "hello" text streams from back-end to front-end as expected. But, the data stream doesn’t stop on call to close method. I want the data stream to close when user clicks the button again. Would appreciate any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I just came across this issue myself. For me, this only happens when developing locally via `ng serve`, using the Webpack dev server to proxy requests to my backend app.
The proxy is implemented using the NPM package `http-proxy-middleware`. There's
an [unresolved issue](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/678) suggesting this is a bug.
When the browser connects directly to the backend API, this issue doesn't happen for me.